# Transformer turns ratio

Tags: transformer

I have a (input) 230V  and (output) 12-0-12 AC to AC transformer.

I want to know how know its primary turns, secondary turns and its secondary voltage?

Comment: Please don't add greetings in the question title. Why are you asking about its secondary voltage when your question states the secondary voltage?

Comment: _”I want to know how know it's primary turns”_ Count them. _”secondary turns”_ Count them. _”it's secondary voltage”_ (12/230) x Input voltage.

Comment: @winny It's probably 240/24 transformer with secondary winding split in the middle.

Comment: @AlexVB Indeed.

Comment: If it happens that you want to know the number of turns in the primary winding and in the secondary winding we unfortunately cannot guess them. They depend on core size, core material and wanted properties. You should find easily transformer design guides and online calculators. They are quite useless if you cannot fill numeric facts they ask. To find which is primary should be easy in your case. It has thinnest wire and biggest DC resistance.

Answer (score 5):

If you can wind some turns onto the transformer without interfering with the winding that are there, add as many as you can comfortably add. Apply 230 volts to the primary and measure the voltage produced by the added winding. Divide the number of added turns by the measured voltage. The result is the turns per volt for any winding. Multiply the calculated turns per volt by the 230 V primary voltage to determine the number of primary turns and by the 24 V secondary voltage to determine the total number of secondary turns.

It would be best to use first measure the applied primary and resulting voltage tor the existing secondary voltage and use those values for the calculations rather than the nominal values. Perform the test with no load connected to the existing secondary winding.